# Not getting connection properly

Tags: java, oracle, swing, netbeans, database-connection

I'm trying to make a Java Swing front end and back end as Oracle Thin I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

on the following statement

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

I've copied the driver jdbc6.jar,and classes12.jar in lib. I am using Oracle 10g and my JDK is 1.8.

Comment: Can you show any code?  How are you attempting to import the classes?

Comment: Try and `import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;` see if you get an error

Answer (score 0):

Could be one or both of these:

- ojdbc6.jar isn't in your class path.  (notices you saids jdbc6.jar missing o)
- Your jdbc url isn't correct.  Please provide some of your codes.